# Can we consider all these satoshi-era wallet being re-activated a good or bad thing for Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, wallet, address

More and more I am seeing news about addresses that was dormant for around 10 years being (re)activated.

Is it positive or negative for bitcoin in the long run ?

Also, how many of those dormant addresses still exist ?

Comment: Q1 is opinion and off-topic. Q2 answered elsewhere, [example](https://crystalblockchain.com/articles/2020-report-on-fund-sources-for-dormant-bitcoin-addresses/)

Comment: Q1 is not offtopic and elsewhere in q2 is not a correct approach.